# hybris: Could not create SourcingResults. Changing order status to SUSPENDED

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I instanlled b2c_acc recipe. after that I commented below extension from localextensions.xml.

```
<extension name='yacceleratorfulfilmentprocess' />
```

and added below extensions.

```
   <extension name='yacceleratorordermanagement' />
   <extension name='warehousing'/>
   <extension name='warehousingbackoffice'/>
    <extension name='consignmenttrackingaddon' />
    <extension name='consignmenttrackingmock' />
    <extension name='consignmenttrackingbackoffice' />
```

Whenever I created an order, it went to Suspended state. When I see the logs, I seen message like 'Could not create SourcingResults. Changing order status to SUSPENDED'.

Why the order is going to Suspended state?

Comment: Did you try receipt which are included OMS? Some configuration or extension may be missing.

Comment: Do you mean 'b2c_b2b_acc_oms' recipe?

Comment: Yes, one of them.

Comment: I installed b2c_acc_oms, now the oder is going to READY state. I logged into back office as 'WarehouseManager' and make the order as complete by clicking on the button 'ship.action.name'. Now I can able to return the order by logging as CustomerSupportAgent. Thanks for the help

Comment: You can find differences in receipts and adding them to yours.Never forget: adding extension to xml file not enough for some extension. You need to run "ant addoninstall" command.